# Closed form for $\ln(2\ln(3\ln(4\ln(5\ln(6…)))))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

A [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773088/does-the-infinite-nested-logarithm-ln2-ln3-ln4-ln5-ln6-converge/2773110#2773110) asked whether the infinite nested logarithm $\ln(2\ln(3\ln(4\ln(5\ln(6…)))))$ has a finite value. It does: I showed with a crude method that the value was at most $2$, and Hagen von Eitzen found a more sophisticated method that gives arbitrarily precise bounds to get an approximate value of $1.36790126$.

Is there any closed form for this expression, or even a form in terms of simple special functions and infinite sums? I tried an [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/), but it came up short; I also speculated that it might be some special value of the Lambert W function, but it doesn't seem to be, although $W(2e) \approx 1.3748$ isn't far off.

Comment: Honestly, I don’t believe a closed form exist.

Comment: There is no reason to expect simple value of Lambert, say $W(a)$, which would imply $a=\ln(2\ln(3\ln(4\ln(5\ln(6…)))))2\ln(3\ln(4\ln(5\ln(6…))))$.

Comment: "Believe me"... There is not a such closed form. Unfortunately I cannot prove this. Anyway, "believe me".

Comment: time to define the Harris Number :)