# Does $\ln (1! \ln (2! \ln (3! \ln (4! \ln (5! \ln (6!\ldots)))))) $ have a finite value and if so what is it?

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, factorial

This question is similar to one concerning [nested logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773088/does-the-infinite-nested-logarithm-ln2-ln3-ln4-ln5-ln6-converge/2773110#2773110) and also [nested radicals involving factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591546/proving-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn-2). If I am correct a quick calculation shows:

$$\ln (1! \ln (2! \ln (3! \ln (4! \ln (5! \ln (6! \ldots ))))))\approx 0.654569$$

Does the sequence implied by this infinite nested logarithm converge to a finite value and if so to what value exactly?

Comment: Heuristically, the $\ln(x)$ function grows more slowly than $\sqrt{x}$ (in particular I believe $\ln(x)<\sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$) so I would expect this to converge by the comparison test with the nested radical sequence, or something similar.

Comment: For clarification, you mean for "$1!(\ln 2!(\ln 3!(\cdots$" to all be in the argument of the first logarithm, including the items in the parentheses?  At first glance, I would interpret $\ln a(b)$ to be $(\ln a)\cdot (b)$ where $b$ is not included as a part of the argument of the logarithm.

Comment: The sequence seems to converge very rapidly. For $n=100$ and $n=200$ , the value differs less than $10^{-200}$. The limit is apparently $$0.65456942883021402957745237107331947\cdots $$ With pari/gp, we can calculate the value with this function : f(n)={m=n;s=m!;while(m>1,m=m-1;s=log(s)*m!);s=log(s);s}

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, sorry my parenthesis were confusing, I edited them to be more clear. I mean for the logarithms to be nested within one another.

Comment: @Peter Yes, this matches almost exactly what I am getting with pari/gp up to 2000!. It does appear to converge very quickly...

Comment: @Goldbug If you increase the precision, you should get exactly the same decimal expansion upto this point.

Comment: But doesn't the numerical calculation rather calculate the sequence $(f_i(i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, for  $f_k(n):=\begin{cases} \ln(n! f(n+1))&, 0\le n<k\\k!  &, n=k \end{cases}$, which assumes that $k!f_\infty(k+1)\approx k!$ for $k\to\infty$ ?

Comment: @Sudix I was also a little worried about this as it seems we are ignoring some large numbers by truncating the nesting? This seems similar to how the numerical calculation was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773088/does-the-infinite-nested-logarithm-ln2-ln3-ln4-ln5-ln6-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the answer seemed to come out correct however...

Comment: They all just calculate the limit of the truncated sequence in that answer. Nobody even touches the question of whether the initial expression actually is a sensible mathematical expression.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\dots}}}}$$
We have that $n!^{2^{-x}} \to 1$, which is sufficient to conclude the above converges. In other words, we have that
$$f(1!f(2!f(3!f(\dots))))$$
Where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, converges. Noting that $g(x)=\ln(x)$ is positive but less than $f(x)$ for all $x>0$, it follows that
$$g(1!g(2!g(3!g(\dots))))$$
also converges. The notation is a little icky, but you could also define it recursively. I checked the number computed by user [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) in the comments in OEIS and through an inverse symbolic calculator, neither of which turned up any results. If you wanted a closed form for what it converges to, you are not likely to find one, though its convergence is rapid and decimal approximations become very accurate very quickly.

**Edit:** slight mistake. That $n!^{2^{-x}}$ converges is sufficient to conclude 
$$\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2! + \sqrt{3! + \dots}}}$$
converges, but it is *not* sufficient to conclude
$$\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{\dots}}}$$
converges. Determining whether the above converges is synonymous to showing 
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty n!^{2^{-x}}$$
Converges. I will not show this, but you can take my word that it does converge. So, because the above converges, we have that $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\dots}}$ converges. Because $\sqrt{x} > \ln(x)$, your infinitely nested logarithm must be bounded by $\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\dots}}$, and therefore must also converge.